# Can't I use operator ""sv for the parameter of fstream()?

Tags: c++, c++17, fstream, string-view

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std::literals;
int main()
{

    auto a = "st"sv;
    std::ifstream in("test.txt"sv, std::ios::in); //error C2664
    std::ifstream in("test.txt"s, std::ios::in);  
}
```

I'm using visual studio. Can't I using the [string-view literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator%22%22sv) `""sv` on fstream? or Am I have to set something?

Comment: If you're using C++17 and doing file operations, you should take a look at `std::filesystem::path`.

Comment: @Kaldrr thank you I'll gonna check that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't.

You can't use it because there is no ctor for `std::ifstream` that accepts an `std::string_view` [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream)
and there is no implicit conversion between `std::string_view`s and the types `if_stream` accepts, hence you have to make a conversion using `staic_cast` or the constructor of `std::string`

---

If you have an `std::string_view` (lvalue), you can use it as follows

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std::literals;
int main()
{

    auto a = "st"sv;
    auto file_location = "test.txt"sv;
    std::ifstream in(std::string(file_location), std::ios::in);  
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ech7Pb)

Comment: Using `file_location.data()` where `const char *` is expected is risky, isn't it? `string_view`'s `data` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated.

Comment: thank you about the answer. But I'm still curious about why fstream with string is okay but string_view is not.

Comment: @sunkue I have added more explanation.